# an error in entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, compiler-errors

what should i do?
i want to get an entry but what is this error?????

```
def gt():
    global e
    string = e.get() 
    print(string)  
def p():
    b.destroy()
    c.destroy()
    w = Label(top, text="here are what you can use:")
    w1 = Label(top, text="qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM123456789")
    w.pack()
    w1.pack()
    L1 = Label(top, text="give me the password")
    L1.pack( side = LEFT)
    e=Entry(top)
    e.pack()
    r = Button(top,text='okay',command=gt)
    r.pack(side='bottom')
    top.mainloop()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Hadi\Desktop\t.py", line 51, in gt
    string = e.get()
NameError: global name 'e' is not defined
```

how can i fix this code?
e is defined but it says that it's not!!!!?

Comment: Are you sure `e` is defined globally and not in a class or something? Show more code.

Comment: You define `e` as a _local_ variable in function `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`global` is used inside function to inform function to use external/global variable instead local one. It doesn't create global variable.

To create global variable you have to use outside function ie.

```
e = None    # or any other value
```

And then you have to use `global e` in `p()` to inform function that you want to assign `Entry()` to external/global variable and function doen't have to create local variable `e`

```
# create global variable - you have to assign any value - ie. `None`
e = None

def gt():
    # global e # you don't need "global" because you doesn't assign new value using `=`
    print(e.get())  

def p():
    # inform function to use external/global variable instead of local one
    global e # you need it because you use `=` to assign new value

    e = Entry(top)
    e.pack()
```

---

**BTW:** You can even skip `e = None` because `global e` plus `e = Entry()` will create global variable (but `global e` withoute `e = ...` will not create global variable).

Sometimes better use `e = None` because it can be usefull information for people which will read your code.